# How can I get direct access to body variable on Mailchimp, using Gibbon (rails wrapper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

We are trying to check if a specific member on a list is subscribed or unsubscribed. We tried

```
gibbon.lists(list_id).members(lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address).retrieve
```

This. Yet, the hash return of the code is wrapped with "Gibbon::Response". How can I get a direct access to the hash itself?? or is it even possible to get access to it?

Comment: Have you added the `params`? This is directly from the gibbon [GIT](https://github.com/amro/gibbon): `gibbon.lists(list_id).members.retrieve(params: {"count": "50", "offset": "50", "status": "subscribed"})`

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well. Though, the data I get is wrapped in `#<Gibbon::Response: ... @body={"id"=>".....", "email_address"=>"......", ..., "status"=>"subscribed"`
But then I want to get the `subscribed` as a return. how should I do it?... @scoopzilla

Comment: That's the response from the API? Then the member is subscribed.

Comment: @scoopzilla Yea... I know it but I want to make rails judge it by itself. And as far as I understood, to do that I need to get the `status` value as mere return of `subscribed` or `unsubscribed`. The problem is that I don't know how to access the `status` value within the `#<Gibbon::Response: ...` bracket.. Does this question even make sense?

Comment: Damn, that was exactly what I was looking for. Has anyone figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

After looking for an answer to this question for a while, and not finding one, I just tested and played around with my code, to finally come up with the solution. It looks like this:

```
Gibbon::Request.lists(list_id).members(user_email).retrieve.body["status"]
```

In your case it would look like this:

```
gibbon.lists(list_id).members(lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address).retrieve.body["status"]
```

This also means that you can retrieve whatever information from the body. Like `email_address` , `merge_fields`, and so on.

Just to make it clear for others, `list_id`is your audience id that you can find in your mailchimp dashboard. It is basically a string of characters that was generated automatically, and that identify the mailing list you have created.

And the `user_email`
is just the email address in quotes.